# TypeORM updating column value

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeorm

I am a bit stumped, with the code I have to update the value of a column. In the below code the column `accountOpeningRequest` doesn't seem to update.

**entity.ts**

```
export class Envelope extends BaseEntity {
..........
.....
  @Column({ type: 'jsonb', nullable: true })
  accountOpeningRequest: any
.....
...
}
```

**service.ts**

```
export class EnvelopeService {
  
private readonly logger = new Logger(EnvelopeService.name)
  
constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Envelope)
    private envelopeRepository: Repository<Envelope>,
) {}
........
.....
...
 const envelope = await this.envelopeRepository.findOne({
    where: { envelopeId: envelopeId },
 })
 this.logger.log('Envelope Data Accnt Opening Process:', envelope)
 if (envelope) {
   this.logger.log('Saving Account Opening Response to DB')
   envelope.accountOpeningRequest = accountOpeningJson
   await this.envelopeRepository.save(envelope)
 }

}
```

All the above log statement print out the appropriate output, but for some reason the `accountOpeningRequest` property doesn't update